# GET in REST when positional argument is not safe

Tags: rest, api, http

So, I know that there is a convention to use `POST` verb when creating a resource and use `GET` when retrieving a one.

In my case, I need to implement an endpoint something like this `api/v1/instance/<hostname>/children`.

Now usually, I wouldn't have a problem with that, what I'm not sure about is that the hostname is in this form: `test1.example.com` or `test2.example.com` or even `https://example.com` and this seems very prone to errors.

Should I use `POST` here instead of `GET` when the positional arguments are not strictly alphanumeric? Is there some best practice for this?

Comment: This is a highly opinion based topic as there is no generally accepted standard and _best practices_ are usually something a whole team agrees on rather than something written in stone. That being said, as long as the `hostname` is URI-valid there is nothing wrong with having it in the API path itself - resources/services are separated by a slash so everything URI-valid between slashes is a perfectly valid argument. Of course, it might get out of hand when using complex paths, but you can redesign your API to accept the hostname as a parameter, i.e. `api/v1/instance/children?host=<hostname>`.

Comment: I would go with common convention for purpose based decision. If you want to have path that is less error prone i would recommend to design it like that `api/v1/instance/{hostname}/{protocol}/children` then you may even do `api/v1/example.com/https/children` or `api/v1/test1.example.com/http/children` in case of `.` missinterpretation you may modify your server to accept path based on regexp or check if there is some param which will dicable assumption that last dot points to a file extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I use POST here instead of GET when the positional arguments are not strictly alphanumeric?

No.

Encoding of data into URI is a well understood problem.  There's no particular reason to start compromising the semantics of your methods just because your identifiers include non-alphanumeric sequences in the path segments.

You might want to look to see what flavors of [URI Templates](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570) are available to you.